# Exercise Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, self-learning, proof-verification

I'm having trouble to understand the following exercise I would appreciate any help?

Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ and let $f:C\rightarrow A$ be an injective map. Define the sets $D_0, D_1, ...$ recursively by setting $D_0:=B\backslash A$, and $D_{n+1}:=f[\,D_n\,]$ for all the natural numbers. Prove that the sets are all disjoints to each other. Also show that if $g: A\rightarrow B$ is a function defined by setting $g(x)= f^{-1}(x)$ when $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$, and $g(x)=x$ when $x\in A\backslash \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ and is a bijection between the two.

For the first part, I've tried to use induction but I have some problems to do the last step. Here is what I have so far.

(1) First we have to show that $D_n\cap D_{n+1}=\varnothing$ for all $n$.

For the base case suppose by contradiction that $D_0\cap D_1 \not= \varnothing$. Then there is some $x\in D_0$ and $x\in D_1$, i.e., $x\in B\backslash A$ and $x\in f[\,B \backslash A \,]$, so we have $x= f(y)$ for $y\in B\backslash A \subseteq C$. But then $f(y)\in A$ by definition of $f$, which contradicts that $x = f(y)\in B\backslash A$.

Now suppose we have already proven the assertion for $n\ge 0$ and we may assume that $D_{n+1} \cap D_{n+2} \not= \varnothing$. Let $x \in D_{n+1} \cap D_{n+2}$. So $x = f(y)$ for $y\in D_{n}$ and $x=f^2(z)$ for $z\in D_n$. Since $f$ is 1:1, we have $y= f(z)$. Then $y=f(z)\in D_{n} \cap D_{n+1}$. But, by inductive hypothesis $D_{n} \cap D_{n+1} = \varnothing$, a contradiction.

(2) Now we have to show $D_n \cap D_{n+1+\ell}=\varnothing$ for all $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$. The base case follows from (1). We may assume that the claim is true for $\ell \ge 0$ and we will show that also hold for $\ell+1$.

By contradiction suppose that $D_n\cap D_{n+1+\ell+1} \not= \varnothing$. Let $x\in D_n\cap D_{n+1+\ell+1}$. So, $x= f^2(z)$ where $z\in D_{n+\ell}$, if we set $y = f(z)$, so $\,y \in D_{n+1+\ell}$.

And there is where I'm stuck. Some hint? I've not try yet the last part of the exercise. Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm not sure if the title is  really appropriate. If someone think that is better idea to change it, for me is ok.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: You left out the conclusion of the exercise statement.

Comment: The conclusion? That $\#A=\#B $ since $g$ is a bijection. Yes I forgot it. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that the claims are trivial if $A=B,$ so suppose not.

To simplify your induction, note that for any $n\in\Bbb N,$ we have $D_{n+1}=f[D_n]\subseteq A$ (since $f:C\to A$), but $D_0=B\setminus A,$ so $D_0=B\setminus A$ is disjoint from $D_{n+1},$ being disjoint from $A.$

Now, suppose that there is some least $m\in\Bbb N$ for which there is some $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{m\}$ such that $D_m\cap D_n\neq\emptyset.$ By the above work, we have that $0<m<n.$ Then $m=j+1$ and $n=k+1$ for some $j,k\in\Bbb N$ with $j<k,$ and there is some $y\in D_{j+1}\cap D_{k+1}.$ By our choice of $m,$ we have that $D_j\cap D_i=\emptyset$ for all $i\in\Bbb N\setminus\{j\}$ (why?), and in particular, $D_j\cap D_k=\emptyset.$ Since $y\in D_{j+1}=f[D_j],$ then $y=f(x_j)$ for some $x_j\in D_j.$ Similarly, $y=f(x_k)$ for some $x_k\in D_k.$ Since $D_j\cap D_k=\emptyset,$ then $x_j\neq x_k,$ from which we readily derive a contradiction. (Why?)

The second part is fairly straightforward. You'll need to use the first part in the proof. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks :). The fist why is  because otherwise contradicts the minimality of $m$. And the second why is because the map is 1:1, then $f(x_j) \not= f(x_k)$ contrary our assumption. Let me work in the other part of the proof I hope, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Right on both counts! Also, even if you don't have trouble, feel free to outline your reasoning here in the comments, and I'll be glad to check it.

Comment: Thanks it'd be a pleasure. I think I got it. Let me revise the complete argument again and in a moment I'll put it here.

Comment: Hi the entire proof was too big so I've put below. I hope the argument is OK. Thanks again for all your help. Happy new year!

Comment: sorry for being too annoying XD but in other part of the book, he is asking for the famous Bernstein Thm. And I thought, If we have two 1:1 maps $A\xrightarrow {f}  B$ and  $B\xrightarrow {g}  A$, and  we restrict the target set of one of them, says the first, so $A\xrightarrow {f}  f[A]$  is naturally a bijection and of course both have the same cardinality, also $f[A]\subseteq B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$ is 1:1 by hypothesis then using the last exercise we can create a bijection $h: f[A] \rightarrow B$ and so, the result follows do you think this is a correct way to do it? Thanks for advance

Comment: Your proof looks good to me at first glance, but I'm on a long road trip, so haven't had the time (or mental coherency) to get into the details, yet. As for the connection to the Bernstein Theorem: that's an excellent question! I suspect you're right, but I'll have to take a look at it when I've had a chance to rest.

Comment: Again, thanks for all you help you are so kind. I'm really sorry if I'm a little annoying with this, and also I hope you have a good trip.

Comment: No problem at all! I've looked your proofs over. Your second is very nice. One thing about the first proof: there is no ambiguity in the rule of $g,$ so $g$ *is* a function from $A$ *into some set.* However, you must justify that $B$ is a codomain of $g$--that is, for every $a\in A,$ we have that $g(a)\in B.$ Showing this shouldn't be difficult. Excellent work!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, is easy to show that the codomain is B. I like it this proof of the Bernstein Schroeder thm (only the proof which use the Tarsky's fixed point thm like me as much as this) because normally is very difficult to follows  the entire argument (well, for me it is XD). Wow is amazing the way in which the book of Terry Tao teach you things, I really love it. I don't know why is underrated (the book) at least where I live.

Answer (score 2):

I put it here hopefully it won't be a problem.

Let define the function $g: A \rightarrow B$ as follows:

$$ x\mapsto \begin{cases} f^{-1}(x),&  \text{if }\,x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i\\
x,&  \text{if }\, x\in A\backslash\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i \end{cases} $$

We claim that the function is well-defined and is a bijection. Since each $D_i$ is disjoint to each other then there is not ambiguity. Also we have  $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i \subset f[C]$ and so the inverse function of $f$ exist [since is a bijection if we restrict the target set to its image ].

Suppose $x,x'\in A$ and $x\not= x'$. We will show that $g(x)\not= g(x')$, i.e., g is a $1:1$ map.

If $x,x'\in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$, so $x=f(y_{i-1})\in f[D_{i-1}]$ and $x'=f(y_{k-1})\in f[D_{k-1}]$ for $i,k>0$. Clearly $y_{i-1}\not= y_{k-1}$ because $f$ is function. Then $g(f(y_{i-1}))=y_{i-1}$ and $g(f(y_{k-1}))=y_{k-1}$ and for what we said above the result follows.  If $x,x'\in A\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$ the result is trivial. Just we need to check when $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$ and $x'\in A\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$. Then $g(x)= y_{i-1}\in D_{i-1}$ [$x= f(y_{i-1})$] and $g(x')=x'$. For the sake of contradiction suppose that $x'=y_{i-1}$. We divide the claim in two parts when $i=1$ and when $i>1$. For the former $x'=y_{i-1}\in B\backslash A$ but $x' \in A$ a contradiction. For the latter, $x'=y_{i-1} \in D_{i-1}\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D_i$ which is again a contradiction. Therefore $x'\not=y_{i-1}$.

In any case we have $g(x)\not= g(x')$. Hence $g$ is an injective map.

To conclude we have to show that $g$ is a surjective map. Let

$$z\in B= B\backslash A \cup A = B\backslash A \cup \bigg(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n \cup A \backslash \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n \bigg) $$

we will show that there is some $x\in A$ such that $g(x)= z$. It is not difficult to show that the three sets are disjoints. Then we analyze the entire problem by cases again.

If $z\in B \backslash A$, so $f(z)\in f[D_0]=D_1\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n  \subseteq A$ and then $g(f(z))= z$ as desired. If $z\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ then we have $z\in D_i$ for $i>0$, so $f(z)\in D_{i+1} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n  \subseteq A$, furthermore $g(f(z))= z$. If $z \in A\backslash \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$, then $g(z)=z$ and we're done.

Thus the map is surjective and injective, i.e, bijective. Furthermore, $\#A =\#B$.

**Corollary**: (Bernstein Thm) Let $f: A \rightarrow B$, and $g: B \rightarrow A$ be injectives maps. Then, there exists a bijective map $h: A\rightarrow B$.

Proof: Clearly  $f: A \rightarrow f[A]$ is a bijection. We define $\tilde h:= f \circ g$. Now, since $f[A]\subseteq B$ and $\tilde h: B \rightarrow f[A]$ is an injection then  there exists a bijective map $h: f[A]\rightarrow B$ as we have shown. Hence the composition with $f$ give us the desired bijection.